# GitHub found my profile picture without me uploading one. How is that?

Tags: github

I just created a new account on GitHub to practice using the API. Somehow my profile now has a very relevant profile picture, which I never uploaded. How did this happen? Was is from the email address I used maybe? If so, again, how?

Comment: Did you use Google to create the account?

Comment: No - email signup

Answer (score 1):

> email signup

If is possible GitHub queried [`en.gravatar.com`](http://en.gravatar.com/), which could have a picture associated to this URL.

Any service using that URL, and aware of gravatar, would then display the same picture.